# IntelliJ Git Compare Weird Issue while trying to compare with Remote

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Iam using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 version. I am trying to compare a local file with remote version. So IntelliJ provides 2 **options**: `Compare with Same Repository Version` and `Compare with Branch`

So when I do `Compare with Same Repository Version`, its showing me correctly.

But when I do `Compare with Branch`, its not showing me correctly. So I did Get Fetch for my project and then only working properly.

**My Query is**: How come `Compare with Same Repository Version` working properly without doing any 'git fetch', as this option too has to compare with Remote itself BUT with same Branch, right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm used to the command line :

- when you run `git diff file` with no extra argument, git shows you a diff between the version in the `HEAD` commit* and the version on disk
  I suspect this is what `Compare with Same Repository Version` does
- to view a diff with the remote version, I would run `git diff origin/master file` ;
  if `origin/master` is not up to date, then I would get a diff with an older version of `file`, as expected, and I would need to `git fetch` to update it
  I suspect this is what `Compare with Branch` does

[*] actually it compares with the *indexed* version : if I had run `git add file` on an intermediate version, I would get the diff with that intermediate version.

Comment: Hi, I have a doubt, In order to work git diff file, then Don't we need to update HEAD locally?

Comment: `HEAD` is always up to date : by definition, it is the active commit. Did I misunderstand your question ?

Comment: No, my query is: How does HEAD always have latest commit, without me doing Git Pull or Fetch? HEAD points to latest local commit to current branch, right? Is this correct?

Comment: okay. So "Compare with Same Repository Version" should be comparing local file code with local HEAD branch(say branch1) or remote branch(ie., origin/branch1)? pls clear me this

Comment: My guess is : with `HEAD`. You can confirm this by reading the docs, or by running `git diff` vs `git diff origin/master` in a terminal, and eyeballing what diff is displayed in IntelliJ

Comment: one last doubt: Suppose I am in dev branch, which is basically unstable one. so when I do git diff origin/dev <somefile>, will this command show differently before and after 'git fetch'?

Comment: Yes : if your local copy of `origin/dev` is late wrt the remote one, `git fetch` will update it. So the two diffs would be against different commits.

Comment: ok got it.. So incase of both "Compare with Same Repository Version" and "Compare with Branch", its better that I do git fetch first before comparing, so that to avoid wrong comparison of file content BTW, Thanks a lot LeGEC :)